# PySpark DataFrame - Calculate First and Last Day Balances for Each Month and Name

Tags: pyspark

I'm working with a PySpark DataFrame in which I have columns containing 'name', 'date', 'month', and 'balance'. I want to calculate the balance for the first and last days of each month for every 'name' in the DataFrame and populate these values in new columns 'balance_on_first_day' and 'balance_on_last_day' for each row corresponding to the respective 'name' and 'month' groups.

I've tried using window functions like first() and last() to compute these values, but I'm encountering issues where some rows have NULL values for either 'balance_on_first_day' or 'balance_on_last_day'.

Here's an example of what I've attempted:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Assuming spark is your SparkSession and df is your DataFrame
# Replace 'name', 'date', 'month', 'balance' with your actual column names

# Example DataFrame creation
data = [
    ("John", "2023-01-05", 1, 1000),
    ("Alice", "2023-01-10", 1, 1200),
    ("John", "2023-02-15", 2, 1500),
    ("Alice", "2023-02-20", 2, 1800),
    ("John", "2023-03-01", 3, 2000),
    ("Alice", "2023-03-25", 3, 2200),
    ("John", "2023-03-31", 3, 2100),
]
columns = ["name", "date", "month", "balance"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Convert 'date' column to date type
df = df.withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('date'))

# Define windows for first and last day balances
window_first_day = Window.partitionBy('name', 'month').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
window_last_day = Window.partitionBy('name', 'month').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedFollowing, Window.unboundedFollowing)

# Calculate first and last day balances using window functions and coalesce
df = df.withColumn('balance_on_first_day', F.coalesce(F.first('balance').over(window_first_day), F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('balance_on_last_day', F.coalesce(F.last('balance').over(window_last_day), F.lit(0)))

# Show the updated DataFrame
df.show()
```

However, this is generating 2 rows for each name-month pair, one with 'balance_on_last_day' NULL and one with 'balance_on_first_day' NULL. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your data actually has rows where the `balance` value is NULL.

In which case, you just need to use `ignorenulls=True` for `first` and `last` function calls to get the first/last non-NULL values.

- Here I've edited your sample data to include some NULL cases.
- Since the windows are actually the same, you don't need to specify it twice
- Finally, if you don't want NULLs for cases where all the balances are actually NULLs, I prefer to use `fillna` instead of `coalesce`

```py
data = [
    ("Alice", "2023-01-10", 1, 1200),
    ("Alice", "2023-02-20", 2, 1800),
    ("Alice", "2023-03-25", 3, 2200),
    ("Alice", "2023-04-01", 4, None),
    ("John", "2023-01-05", 1, 1000),
    ("John", "2023-02-15", 2, 1500),
    ("John", "2023-03-01", 3, 2000),
    ("John", "2023-03-02", 3, None),
    ("John", "2023-03-31", 3, 2100),
    ("John", "2023-04-01", 4, None),
    ("John", "2023-04-02", 4, 200),
    ("John", "2023-04-03", 4, 300),
    ("John", "2023-04-04", 4, 400),
    ("John", "2023-04-05", 4, None),
]
columns = ["name", "date", "month", "balance"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Convert 'date' column to date type
df = df.withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('date'))

# Only need to define one window
window = Window\
  .partitionBy('name', 'month')\
  .orderBy('date')\
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

# Call first-last with ignorenulls=True
df = df\
  .withColumn('first', F.first('balance', ignorenulls=True).over(window))\
  .withColumn('last',  F.last('balance', ignorenulls=True).over(window))

# Fill NULL with zeroes if necessary
df = df.fillna(0, ['first', 'last'])

# Show the updated DataFrame
df.orderBy('name', 'month').show()
```

```
+-----+----------+-----+-------+-----+----+
| name|      date|month|balance|first|last|
+-----+----------+-----+-------+-----+----+
|Alice|2023-01-10|    1|   1200| 1200|1200|
|Alice|2023-02-20|    2|   1800| 1800|1800|
|Alice|2023-03-25|    3|   2200| 2200|2200|
|Alice|2023-04-01|    4|   NULL|    0|   0|
| John|2023-01-05|    1|   1000| 1000|1000|
| John|2023-02-15|    2|   1500| 1500|1500|
| John|2023-03-01|    3|   2000| 2000|2100|
| John|2023-03-02|    3|   NULL| 2000|2100|
| John|2023-03-31|    3|   2100| 2000|2100|
| John|2023-04-01|    4|   NULL|  200| 400|
| John|2023-04-02|    4|    200|  200| 400|
| John|2023-04-03|    4|    300|  200| 400|
| John|2023-04-04|    4|    400|  200| 400|
| John|2023-04-05|    4|   NULL|  200| 400|
+-----+----------+-----+-------+-----+----+
```